# Singleton ES6 Module being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am not sure why the module here which has a console.log is being called multiple times.  I thought this was a **singleton**.

So if I'm importing this module into other modules, since this is a singleton I did not expect the console.log to be called every time...only the first time it's imported by a module but after that I thought that, even when imported by subsequent modules, since it's a singleton, then I shouldn't see a ton of these being logged:

src/graphql/db/InMemory/**InMemoryDB.ts**

```
console.log('inMemoryDB');
const inMemoryDb = newDb();
inMemoryDb.public.none(fs.readFileSync('001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
export default inMemoryDb;
```

what I'm seeing when I run initially run tests **or** initially start my service which uses this singleton, are 6-7 `inMemoryDB` being logged.  Even after I changed it to this, same deal:

```
const inMemoryDb = () => {
  console.log('inMemoryDB');
  return newDb();
}
inMemoryDb.public.none(fs.readFileSync('001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
export default inMemoryDb();
```

So for example when I start my graphql service, I get like 6-7 of those console.logs when I run `yarn graphql-dev`

```
"graphql-dev": "yarn compile-graphql && yarn start-graphql-dev",
"compile-graphql": "tsc -b ./src/graphql",
"start-graphql-dev": "node --optimize_for_size --trace-warnings --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --no-warnings dist/graphql/server.js"
```

deep down in my graphql code, it uses that in-memory DB singleton like this (based on the **first** implementation above):

```
const inMemoryPgDb = inMemoryDb;
```

Comment: Can you share more details to replicate the issue such as are you using any bundler such as webpack, babel etc and what plugins are you using.

Comment: no bundler, these are services so just folder for slack, folder for graphql.  In them a package.json, and a tsconfig.  Simply uses tsconfig to output the files to dist.

Comment: Agree with you that the call happens and console is called but the value does not variable does not change. Check the example https://codesandbox.io/s/es6-singletons-gwrv3?file=/src/secret.js

Comment: What do you mean your tests? What kind of tests and how are you running tests?

Comment: nevermind, I removed the tests part, I was writing in the wrong post

Comment: I just wonder even if the value..the DB instance created once only didn't change and even if I had multiple places importing this module, why would console.log be called every time?  Is every import re-running all code in that module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with you that the call happens and console.log is called but the value of variable does not change.
Check the example for reference

[Singleton example](https://codesandbox.io/s/es6-singletons-gwrv3?file=/src/secret.js)

OK, Why there is multiple console.log ?
In the above code you are giving a function instance with return type and wherever the module function is referred it gets called. since we are executing that function.

Each module is separate JavaScript program. It combines into a single program
at the time of execution.

Comment: I get multiple console logs on either example, not just the one with the function call.

Comment: In JS each module is a Js program. So whenever the module is referred in other file, it will be called. I hope this answer your question.

Comment: I think not, according to es6 specifications modules are evaluated only once even if they are imported multiple times, but there are some exceptions when it comes to nested projects and so but still modules are treated differently than a normal js program. So the above case is an exception @SatishPai